# Drawing piles of rectangles using python turtle

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How should I make this?

[image]

I am supposed wide and height are 50 pixels

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? We have to see your code to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `turtle.stamp()` method to stamp each cell, and the `random.choice()` method to choose random colors from a list of colors:

```
import turtle
from random import choice

def grid(rows, cols, x, y, size=50):
    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.shapesize(size / 20, size / 20)
    turtle.penup()
    for i in range(rows):
        turtle.setpos(x, y - size * i)
        for _ in range(cols):
            turtle.forward(size)
            turtle.color("black", choice(["white", "grey"]))
            turtle.stamp()

grid(5, 5, -200, 200)
```

Output:

[image]